# Sound problem in my Desktop

Tags: audio, troubleshooting, sound-card, dell-dimension

I have a Dell Dimension 5150 desktop, I am not able to hear any sound when any audio file is playing, I have checked the audio drivers and have downloaded the drivers from the dell site,

Is this a Hardware problem with the sound card, in case is there any way to find out whether its the problem with the sound card or any suggestions is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Stupid but obvious things:

Have you made sure that the speakers are working / plugged in?

Do the speakers have their own power button?

Do the speakers have their own volume knob?

Have you tried raising the volume from the computer?

can you hear any sound in any application?

Comment: Checked everything....everything is fine.......

When i right click the Sound, Video and game controllers in device manager and see its properties , i didnt find anything under the general tab, is something missing

Answer (score 0):

do you have additional audio controllers installed (e.g. a USB headset)?

open the **Control Panel** > **Sound & Audio Devices** (**Audio** tab) and make sure your soundcard (probably SoundMAX) is set as default playback device.

Comment: I have checked the Audio Tab in Sound & Audio devices, under the Sound PLay BAck and Sound Recording boxes i have selected the Sigma Tel Audio and all down below i have checked the option "Use Only default devices"

Comment: which OS, XP or Vista? can you post the motherbord model (SIW will give you this information)? http://www.gtopala.com/download/siw.exe

Comment: OS is Windows XP Professional SP3

Mother Board Model : 0WG261

Comment: ok, i have a similar machine here, a Dimension 5000 and i couldn't get the sound to work with Dell's driver (although it installed correctly), i grabbed a driver from HP/Compaq instead and it works. but before we go any further, is this a fresh installation or did the sound work before and it just stopped?

Comment: this is a fresh installation

Comment: right, back to SIW, can you open PCI, do you see a Audio Device named Intel 82801FB or something similar? did you install the chipset driver from the Dell support page? if not, do it and then install the audio driver again. http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&releaseid=R114566&SystemID=DIMENSION%205150/E510&servicetag=&os=WW1&osl=en&deviceid=3268&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=2&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=1&libid=27&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&fileid=150654

Comment: Yes, i first installed the chip set drivers restarted my system and then went ahead with the audio driver installation. Meanwhile

PCI Info:

type: PCI-x
Class type: Hi-Definition Audio
Manufacturer: Intel corporation
Device Name: 82801g (ICH7 Family) High definition Audio

Comment: right, here'a newer driver than the one from DELL: http://download.cnet.com/Audio-SIGMATEL-STAC-92XX-C-Major-HD-Driver-Version-A07/3000-2110_4-131145.html

Comment: I am sorry no change, meanwhile i am getting problem with my wireless thing.. anything related

Comment: Molly, Thanks for ur precious time, what could be the final step to get it rectified